# WiX extension for burn / bootstrapper

Tags: wix

I'm using `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication` to create a bootstrapper installer using WiX. In it I'm using `FileSearch` from the `WixUtilExtension` library (part of a standard WiX install). I'm not quite happy with the logic it's using though, and want to do things just a little differently, but I can't find an easy way to do that. I see my options as:

1. Create my own managed bootstrapper, this would mean also creating an entire UI experience, which feels like an awful lot of yak shaving.
2. Create my own library *like* `WixUtilExtension` to inject some of my own custom logic.

I favour option 2, given that I have no interest in replacing the overall process offered by `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication`, but I'm having a hard time finding how to create a burn-centric extension. I can find detail about creating extensions which then get mapped to custom actions (MSI only, not burn bootstrapper), or perform other pre-processing and compiler actions which aren't relevant to my needs here.

How do I go about creating a *burn* extension? Would I be better off just biting the bullet and creating my own managed bootstrapper, or is there some simple option I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to what you want is the BAFunctions.dll that Neil initially wrote for his [ExtendedBA](http://wixextba.codeplex.com/).  He was able to merge most of that into WiX 3.8.  There's example code in [Burn's Samples directory](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/burn/Samples/bafunctions).

Comment: So how would I be injecting my custom logic? Extend the BAFunctions library? Is C++ the only option there?